# importing lmfit succesfull but importing Model from lmfit not

Tags: python, import, lmfit

I have installed lmfit trough PIP

```
pip install lmfit==0.7.2
```

importing lmfit in ipython notebook seems to work. 
That is, the import does not give any error messages and I can call a bunch of functions from lmfit.

However when i try to import Model from lmfit it gives me an import error:

```
from lmfit import Model
```

The import error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-151-3ba1b6658da4> in <module>()
----> 1 from lmfit import Model

ImportError: cannot import name Model
```

I assume this has to do with a failed installation but do not know how to diagnose this further and/or how to fix it. Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: what about if you run `from lmfit import *` --does that get you the functionality you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the Model Class is new to lmfit-py release 0.8.1 so you may have to update lmfit.

(I have the offline documentation for 0.7.2 which does not include a section on the Model Class, but the documentation for version 0.8.1 has it)