# Python: importing lmfit.models fails

Tags: python, import, lmfit

This post is related to my [other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48874733/fit-triple-gauss-to-data-python) where I was told to use lmfit to fix my problem.

I installed lmfit in anaconda Prompt with **conda install --channel "conda-forge" lmfit** which worked. 
But now when I try to use it in my Programm I get the following error:

> *ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lmfit.model'; 'lmfit' is not a package*

Thats how the beginning of my Program looks like:

```
import numpy as np
import math
import scipy    #I dont need scipy, but I read, that lmfit needs scipy. It doesn't change anything when its there or not.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from lmfit.model import GaussianModel
```

I also tried to import lmfit seperatly like:

```
import lmfit
from lmfit.model import GaussianModel
```

But it doesn't work either...

I tried everything from the [lmfit website](http://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/installation.html#installation), but using the "git"-thing in Anaconda Prompt gives me an error (something like command doesn't exist)

I also found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27291982/importing-lmfit-succesfull-but-importing-model-from-lmfit-not), and importing **from lmfit import *** works. Now I have the problem that I somehow need to import the GaussianModel, which I don't know how to do. If I just add **from lmfit import GaussianModel** I get the Error

> *ImportError: cannot import name 'GaussianModel'*

I also read something about the order of importing packages and modules is important - is this what the problem is about? How can I fix this?

I work on windows with anaconda/spider.

Comment: It's plural: `from lmfit.models import GaussianModel`.

Comment: That, however, does not explain the error message you quote. Check that you're not running this in a directory where you have an `lmfit` directory or `lmfit.py` file, since in that case, Python will attempt to import that (which is likely not the installed package).

Comment: Just to be sure if I understand you correctly: I need to go to preferences - Current Working directory and need to choos the directory where lmfit (lmfit-0.9.7-py36_0.json) is (which would be Anaconda/ conda-meta for me)? Or did I missunderstand you?

Comment: Either `pip install lmfit` or `conda install -c gsecars lmfit` should work.  After seeing one of those work, verify that you can do `import lmfit` from the python or ipython prompt in spyder or from a python session started in the "anaconda prompt".  You do NOT need to be in the folder where `lmfit` got unpacked.  In fact,  you don't want a folder or file named `lmfit` in your working directory -- that will cause the confusion Evert is talking about.

Comment: No, you want to avoid the directory where you downloaded lmfit, and where it's installed. I don't know how Spyder usually works with directories, since I'm used to the command line, but it seems likely there's a clash between filenames.

Comment: Here's a thing to try: *only* `import lmfit`, then `print(lmfit.__file__`) will tell you what file (with its full path) it is using. See if that looks like the correct file, or an incorrect file.

Comment: @MNewville @Evert  Thank you very much, now it works! I did everything you told me, i guess that `conda install -c gsecars lmfit` made it work :) The path of my file is the following (for others which have the same problem): _C:\Users\Carina\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\lmfit-0.9.8-py3.6.egg\lmfit\__init__.py_